# how to open jpg files full size

Tags: windows-photo-gallery

I've recently enrolled in an online course that is presented in a Java window (no ability to copy/paste text). I have been taking notes with print screen and then saving the image via MS Paint as a jpg. When I want to go over my class notes they only open at 30-40% of their original size. This makes it to view the slide show w/o having to enlarge each one.

For a time I was using extended desktop and print screen would capture the image from both monitors. I would then crop out the unwanted portion and voila the images appeared full size. After a brief online chat w/MS it was determined that the way a jpg is saved will determine how it opens. Can anyone recommend a solution to either saving them or changing the properties of the file itself. I have a SONY VAIO laptop w/VHP32 on a Pentium 2 @ 1.6Ghz w/2GB RAM. I use  Windows Photo Gallery to view them. TIA

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as a general rule, you should use a file type *other* than JPG for images with a lot of text.  With JPG, you tend to get a lot of artifacts around text.  You're better off with GIF or PNG.

Answer (score 1):

First off, on a Windows machine, you can press ALT+PrintScreen to capture just the active window instead of the whole screen.  If you click your Java window before hitting ALT+PrintScreen, there will be no need to crop.

(If you have Microsoft OneNote installed, you can also try pressing Win+S to capture a screen shot, then drag a selection box around the area you want to capture.)

For screens you already captured, if you have not already done so, I would recommend that you crop all of the images using MS Paint (or even better, the excellent, free Paint.NET program).

Finally, I would recommend that instead of viewing screen shots in Windows Photo Gallery, you should assemble your screen shots into a Word or Powerpoint document, one page per shot, in Landscape orientation.  You can then use the Reading Mode or Print Layout mode to view them sequentially, and you can easily print a set to a printer or PDF file.  If any need further size or cropping adjustments, you can use the tools provided in those programs.  (If you don't own Microsoft Office, I am sure that the free OpenOffice suite will serve you just as well for this task.)

Comment: Whoa, I never knew that you could copy only the active window. Nice!

Comment: Neither did I, I'll try that today. I try 2 b a minimalist w/apps but I'll try 1 note as well. many 10x.